# How do I generate all combinations of list elements to a given length with iterate?

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to write a function using `iterate` which should generate all combinations of the elements:

```
f :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
f [1,2] = 
  [ [[1] , [2]]                  -- all combinations of length 1
  , [[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,2]],   -- all combinations of length 2
  , [[1,1,1],... ]               -- all combinations of length 3
  , ...                          -- and so on
  ]                              -- infinitely
```

I've tried the following approach

```
f :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
f list = iterate genLists list

genLists :: [a] -> [[a]]       
genLists list  = [ [k] | k<-list ]
```

However, Hugs gives me the following error:

```
Type error in application
*** Expression     : iterate genLists list
*** Term           : genLists
*** Type           : [a] -> [[a]]
*** Does not match : [[a]] -> [[a]]
*** Because        : unification would give infinite type
```

I don't really know why I get the error. Also, how can I generate those combinations using only `iterate`? I cannot import any other module since this is an assignment.

Comment: Try `f xs = iterate genLists (map (\x -> [x]) xs) where genLists xss = (:) <$> xs <*> xss`.

Comment: Undefined variable "<*>"

Comment: Depending on the version of the Haskell platform that you're using, you may need to `import Control.Applicative`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets see why you get the error:

```
iterate  :: (a  -> a    ) -> a -> [a]
genLists :: [a] -> [[a]]
```

As you can see, `iterate` takes a function that takes and returns the same type. However, `genLists` doesn't do that. It takes a list and returns a list of lists.

Since you actually want `f :: [a] -> [[[a]]]`, `genLists` return type is actually fine. However, its argument type is wrong. It has to be of type `genLists :: [[a]] -> [[a]]`:

```
f :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
f xs = iterate genLists [[x] | x <- xs]
    where
       genLists yss = [ x : ys | x <- xs , ys <- yss]
```

Comment: You are rigth about those types. I didn't realized that.

Can i also ask why u wrote ys<- ys ? What did u meant by that?

Comment: @KamilK: Copy error. Fixed ^^". Meant `ys <- yss`, e.g. "take one list of the list of lists".

Comment: Damn its good.  Thanks a lot. It is really good. I spent 2h on figuring why it didnt worked. Thanks one more time

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible implementation, using the applicative style (which you can learn more about [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors)).

```hs
import Control.Applicative

f :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
f xs = iterate genLists $ map pure xs
  where
    genLists xss = (:) <$> xs <*> xss
```

Then,

```
λ> take 3 $ f [1,2]
[[[1],[2]],[[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,2]],[[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]]]
```

Here is an alternative, if you don't want to or cannot use applicative stuff:

```hs
f :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
f xs = iterate genLists $ map (\x -> [x]) xs
  where
    genLists xss = [y : ys | y <- xs, ys <- xss]
```

Comment: OP is probably new to Haskell and doesn't know `Applicative` yet.

Comment: Hi thanks for sollution it works well. But the thing is that i cant import anything. So there have to be a sollution witout using Applicative type

Comment: @Jubobs: Sure, but since this is a Hugs error message, I guess OP takes some kind of Haskell class with restricted imports or similar (haven't seen Hugs being used anywhere lately beside Haskell classes)

Comment: @Zeta Good call. I didn't know this was a Hugs error message.